# yup validates the date before being able to manually enter the whole year

Tags: typescript, yup

I have a datePicker with Formik field and a yup validation for date (DOB). my format is MM/dd/yyyy. But I have a bug: when I try to manually set the date, I insert 12/02 for month and day, but on year, I insert only a digit, and it automatically saves to a valid year without waiting for me to insert the whole year, why?

my validation schema looks like this:
`export const Schema = object().shape({ dateOfBirth: date().nullable()    })`

when typing only a digit for year, it will save the year as 1902